# Drawflow in Angular

Tags: angular, flowchart

I have been trying to use the Drawflow library (https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow) in Angular.

I am using the solution in this post: [Drawflow library on Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267792/drawflow-library-on-typescript) , but unfortunately when I add  to my .html component it doesn't show anything. Does anybody know what might be going wrong? Or can recommend me any other tools to draw flowcharts in Angular?

this is my .html file in which i try to show the component:

```
<div class="containercanvas" >
  <app-drawflow></app-drawflow>
</div>
```

And this is my drawflow.component.ts

```
import { Component, Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Drawflow from 'drawflow';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-drawflow',
  templateUrl: './drawflow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drawflow.component.css']
})
export class DrawflowComponent implements OnInit {
  editor: Drawflow;

  constructor(private hostElRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!!this.hostElRef?.nativeElement) {
      const { nativeElement } = this.hostElRef;
      this.initDrawFlow(nativeElement);
    }
  }

  private initDrawFlow(el: HTMLElement): void {
    try {
      if (!!el) {
        this.editor = new Drawflow(el);
        this.editor.reroute = true;
        this.editor.editor_mode = 'edit';
        // this.editor.drawflow = {}
        this.editor.start();
      } else {
        console.error('Drawflow host element does not exist');
      }

    } catch (exception) {
      console.error('Unable to start Drawflow', exception);
    }
  }


}
```

This is my editor object:
https://gyazo.com/59a5d4910f93706757840118aee29034

Comment: It's a CSS issue. You need set the html,body hight at 100%, I've used it with angular 17 and it working fine

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you confused the use of a directive with that of a component according to the example you are following;

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Drawflow from 'drawflow';



@Directive({
  selector: '[appNgDrawFlow]'
})
export class DrawflowDirective implements OnInit {
  editor: Drawflow | undefined;

  constructor(private hostElRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!!this.hostElRef?.nativeElement) {
      const { nativeElement } = this.hostElRef;
      this.initDrawFlow(nativeElement);
    }
  }

  private initDrawFlow(el: HTMLElement): void {
    try {
      if (!!el) {
        this.editor = new Drawflow(el);
        this.editor.reroute = true;
        this.editor.editor_mode = 'edit';
        // this.editor.drawflow = {}
        this.editor.start();
      } else {
         console.error('Drawflow host element does not exist');
      }

    } catch (exception) {
      console.error('Unable to start Drawflow', exception);
    }
  }
}
```

And use the directive like this:

```
<div class="containercanvas" appNgDrawFlow ></div>
```