# DrawFlow Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I'm trying to use the DrawFlow library in Angular 14

This is my component:

drawing-board.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Drawflow from 'drawflow';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-drawing-board',
  templateUrl: './drawing-board.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drawing-board.component.css']
})
export class DrawingBoardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  editor:Drawflow|null= null;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let element = <HTMLElement> document.getElementById('drawflow');
    console.log(element);
    this.editor = new Drawflow(element);
    this.editor.reroute = true;
    this.editor.curvature = 0.5;
    this.editor.reroute_fix_curvature = true;
    this.editor.reroute_curvature = 0.5;
    this.editor.force_first_input = false;
    this.editor.line_path = 1;
    this.editor.editor_mode = 'edit';

    this.editor.start();
  }

}
```

drawing-board.component.html

```html
<div id="drawflow" class="">
</div>
```

And use in this mode:

```html
<app-drawing-board></app-drawing-board>
```

but doesn't work, only see an empty div html

[image]

I need to edit more atributes?
or is a bad implementation?

Comment: Check out the comments @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72216987/drawflow-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

change the component to be a stand alone component. You can do that by editing the @Component decorator and adding the bottom lines.

https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

```
standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule]
```

then you can import this as its own module directly to the location you need it or directly into the app.module.ts file.

```
@NgModule({
… omitted 
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    DrawingBoardComponent
enter code here
  ],
… omitted 
})
```

the cause is the component appears to not be invoked and is not loaded into the closest adjacent module.  So to fix this annoying issue, in essence each component becomes it own module and it also allows for lazy component loading - which fixes some another initialization errors you might encounter.

you can read about the reasons why and further information about the technology at angular and I picked this blog post.  I don't know that person and I am not affiliated with them.

https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

https://kinsta.com/blog/lazy-loading-in-angular/